# Cast uuid into a jsonb field

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE uuid_items (
  u uuid
);

CREATE TABLE jsonb_items (
  j jsonb
);
```

```
INSERT INTO uuid_items (u) values ('6de8874f-99f0-4b05-8c83-b904b3065ff0');
INSERT INTO jsonb_items (j) values ('"6de8874f-99f0-4b05-8c83-b904b3065ff0"');
```

Now, I would like to join `uuid_items` on `jsonb_items`. Something like so:

```
SELECT * from uuid_items JOIN jsonb_items ON uuid_items.u::jsonb = jsonb_items.j;
```

This will give me the error:

```
Query Error: error: cannot cast type uuid to jsonb
```

I thought of using something like jsonb_build_array as a hack:

```
SELECT * from uuid_items JOIN jsonb_items ON jsonb_build_array(uuid_items.u)->0 = jsonb_items.j;
```

But I wonder: is there a better way? How could I cast uuid_items.u, into a valid jsonb value?

You can play with the [playground here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d49Y4Q9bia2ySrsBwDmBLV/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either convert both to `text`:

```
WHERE u::text = j ->> 0
```

or convert both to `jsonb`:

```
WHERE to_jsonb(u) = j
```

or convert both to `uuid`:

```
WHERE u = (j ->> 0)::uuid
```

Choose according to the indexes you have in place. Best practice is to use the proper data type (`uuid`) for both columns.